# Update amount in cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this method that checks if coupon is valid or not. I would like to update the total amount in the current_cart when coupon is valid. Currently I'm getting this error `NoMethodError in CouponsController#redeem undefined method amount for nil:NilClass`

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

coupons_controller.rb

**Update4**

```
 def redeem
     @coupon = Coupon.find_by_discount_code(params[:discount_code])
  if @coupon.blank?
     redirect_to :back
     flash[:notice] = "Coupon is Invalid!"
  else 
     @current_cart = Cart.find(current_cart.id)
     @current_cart.amount = current_cart.amount - @coupon.amount
     current_cart.save
     redirect_to :back
     flash[:notice] = "Coupon is Valid!"
  end
end
```

**Update 1**

```
application_controller.rb

  def current_cart 
    Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound 
    cart = Cart.create 
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
    cart
  end

  helper_method :current_cart
end
```

**update3**

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id) 
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    end
    current_item
  end


  def total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
  end

  def tax_rate
    tax_amount = 0 
    line_items.each do |item|
      tax_amount += (item.product.price * item.quantity) * item.product.tax_rate.rate
    end
    tax_amount
  end    

  def amount
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price } + tax_rate + fee
  end

  def fee
    shipment_amount = 0 
    line_items.each do |item|
      if item.quantity <= 1
        shipment_amount = item.product.shipment.fee
      else
        shipment_amount = item.product.multiple_shipment.fee
      end
    end
    shipment_amount
  end
end
```

cart/show.html.erb

```
<%= number_to_currency current_cart.amount %>
```

Comment: Either `current_cart` or `@coupon` is nil. Since you have given a check for `@coupon`, most probably `current_cart` might be nil. Check whether you have set that correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Sajin!! I know this might sound silly but kind of a newbie here... if current_cart is nil, how do I change that?

Comment: Can you please share the code where you are setting current_cart

Comment: Please check out update 1

Comment: @current_cart = current_cart. I added this and the error goes away but the amount does not update. Any ideas?

Comment: try calling `@current_cart.save` after assigning the value

Comment: Hmmm weird... Now I'm getting `undefined method save for 0.16e2:BigDecimal` . What does that mean? The code is according to update 2.

Comment: You will have to add a column in your carts table

Comment: `rails g migration add_save_amount_to_carts save_amount:integer`  something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `blank?` method like:

```
def redeem
  @coupon = Coupon.find_by_discount_code(params[:discount_code])
  if @coupon.blank?
   redirect_to :back
   flash[:notice] = "Coupon is Invalid!"
  else 
   current_cart.amount = current_cart.amount - @coupon.amount
   redirect_to :back
   flash[:notice] = "Coupon is Valid!"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Uday kumar das!! Now I' getting `undefined method  amount= for #<Cart:0x007fec58bfec98> Did you mean? amount`

Comment: Can u paste the value of `current_cart` here. Accept the answer if you got your answer correctly.

Comment: @current_cart = current_cart. I added this and the error goes away but the amount does not update. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe `new_amount = current_cart.amount - @coupon.amount` and then `current_cart.update(amount: new_amount)`

Comment: I added an amount column to carts table and update 4 works. But still not updating the amount on cart/show.html.erb. Any ideas?

Comment: replace amount function in cart.rb with `save_amount || line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price } + tax_rate + fee`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def redeem
    @coupon = Coupon.find_by_discount_code(params[:discount_code])
    if @coupon.blank?
      redirect_to :back
      flash[:notice] = "Coupon is Invalid!"
    else 
       @current_cart = Cart.find(current_cart.id)
       @current_cart.amount = @current_cart.amount - @coupon.amount
       @current_cart.save
       redirect_to :back
       flash[:notice] = "Coupon is Valid!"
    end
end
```

Comment: `undefined method amount= for #<Cart:0x007fec5da4bea0> Did you mean? amount`

Comment: can you share your cart.rb and the fields of carts table

Comment: Thank you for your help and time @Sajin, please check out update 3

Comment: amount is a model method, not a field in the table. So you cannot update that

Comment: Is there a way I can switch things around and get it to work?

Comment: Yea. if you are using save_amount as field name then you will have to do `@current_cart.save_amount = @current_cart.amount - @coupon.amount`

Comment: I added the column amount to the cart table and all works well without an error. But still won't update cart/show.html.erb
`<%= number_to_currency current_cart.amount %>`

Comment: I added an amount column to carts table and update 4 works. But still not updating the amount on cart/show.html.erb. Any ideas?